# How to branch a repository from eclipse in bit bucket?

Tags: eclipse, git, git-branch

I have a android project version 1 code in my eclipse i want to branch it in bit bucket(Keep the v1 code aside in bit bucket), so what are the steps to achieve it? so that i can able to start coding for version 2.

Answer (score 0):

"egit" is an eclipse plugin that should get you started. Here is how you create a branch from the egit manual -

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseGit/article.html#team_operations_branch